# Rails html_escape all values

Tags: ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-4, xss, html-escape-characters

I would like to escape all the attributes of a model when fetching the data from DB so that it would avoid XSS. Also, if there are any new columns added in the future it should be escaped by default if I did this.

I want to ERB::Util.html_escape() all the values whenever we are fetching from the database. Is there any efficient way to do this?

Comment: Can you provide some more context?.... What do you mean by "escape HTML"? What do you mean by "all values from the database"? What do you mean by "avoid XSS"? At a guess, I would say that your database contains arbitrary user-inputted data, which you want to expose as raw HTML -- which is absolutely 100% **NOT** avoiding XSS; it's the exact opposite of this.

Comment: @tomlord to be fair the  XSS attack doesn't actually occur until you output the unsafe strings in a page. Rails deals with this by automatically escaping all strings that you output. This was introduced in Rails 4 if my memory serves me correctly.